# Cakephp: run a series of custom classes using APP:objects()

Tags: cakephp

What I want to do:

```
foreach(APP::objects('class','Events') as $event) {
    APP:uses($event,'Events');
}
```

What I have done:

```
App::build(array(
    'Events' => array('%s' . 'Events' . DS)
), App::REGISTER);
```

The 'Events' location shows up in the output of `APP::paths()` but the classes therein do not show in `APP::objects('class')` or any other type that I have tries. according to the API 'class' is a valid type.

I am trying to put all of my event listeners in the 'Events' folder and call them in the bootstrap to initialise them, but I cannot get them to show up. if I call them individually using `APP::uses('foo','Events')` they work fine but it rankles me to have to do this when I SHOULD be able to have them load themselves automagically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some experimentation I found that registering the 'Events' path also registered it as an object type. The classes in the Events directory are accessible from `APP:objects('Events')` making my new code:

```
foreach(APP::objects('Events') as $event) {
    APP:uses($event,'Events');
}
```

this makes all my defined events accessible in my controllers. yay